# Array in Foreach (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I want to use array in foreach loop but failed, here is my code:

```
foreach($this->db->get_where('mytable', array('result' => '1 or 2', 'id' => 'foo'))->result_array()
```

I think `'result' => '1 or 2'`piece has a problem but I couldn't find out how can I use array in this kind of foreach.

I want to say `SELECT * WHERE RESULT = 1 OR 2, ID = FOO IN MYTABLE`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use active record as below.

```
$arrResult = $this->db
->where('id','foo')
->where_in('result',array(1,2))
// alternative to above condition
//->where('(result = 1 OR result = 2)') 
->get('mytable')
->result_array();

foreach($arrResult as $result){
    // run code based on $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how codeigniter but your foreach looks wrong.

try:

```
$resultArray = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('result' => '1 or 2', 'id' => 'foo')->result_array();
foreach($resultArray  as $result){
    // run code based on $result;
}
```

this is the way an foreach statement should look.

from codeigniter manual I got for you this [database manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$where = "ID = FOO and RESULT = 1 OR RESULT = 2";
$this->db->where($where);
$resultArray = $this->db->result_array();
foreach($resultArray as $result){
    // run code based on $result;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's same but 'result' => '1 or 2' part is not working. If I write 'result' => '1 or 2' it only gets result = 1 and if I write result => '2 or 1', it only gets result = 2

Comment: i edited the answer with manually created WHERE to suit your needs.

Comment: You forgot to add brackets.It should be `$where = "ID = FOO and (RESULT = 1 OR RESULT = 2)";`

Answer (score 0):

It will be more clean if you do like this:

```
$result = $this->db->where('id', 'foo')->where_in('result', array(1, 2))->get('mytable')->result_array();

foreach($result as $r) {

}
```